# Continue loop between classes after wrong input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a class that is going to sum a number of whole numbers that is collected from the console window. The class first asks for how many numbers to sum and then reads that many integers from the console.

If the user enters a number with a decimal, which isn't allowed, I have another class called Input.cs that sends back a message that asks them to try again. 
the class has 4 methods, WriteProgamInfo, ReadInput, SumNumbers and ShowResults.
WriteProgamInfo just prints some info with `Console.WriteLine`, ReadInput asks how many numbers the user wants to add,

```
private void ReadInput()
{
    Console.Write("Number of values to sum? ");
    numOfInput = Input.ReadIntegerConsole(); //This here is from the Input class that sends an error message if a decimal is being used. This works fine.
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But now comes the issue that I have, in SumNumbers it asks the user to give the value of the number that he/she wants to add using a for loop that is dependant on what the user inputs in ReadInput.

```
// asks for which numbers to be added, based on how many times
// is given by user in ReadInput
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++) // Loop that asks the quesion d
    {
        Console.Write("Please give the value no. " + index + " (whole number):");
        //This here is from the Input class that sends an error message if a decimal
        //is being used. This is where I have a problem. 
        num = Input.ReadIntegerConsole2();
        sum += num;
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that I want the error message to continue the for loop after having sent the message. 
For instance, I want to sum 2 numbers, so I first add 1, then the console prints: Please give the value no.2 (whole number): but, let's say I then type 1.6 which isn't allowed, the console then prints: Wrong input. Please try again: , Now this is where I want it to continue with the same question as before: "Please give the value no.2 (whole number):"

How do I do this?
The input class looks like this:

```
public static int ReadIntegerConsole2()
{
    int input;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        return input;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. Please try again: ");
    Console.Write("Please give the value no. " + /*index from SumNumbers + */" (whole number):");
    return ReadIntegerConsole2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the same pattern used by Int32.TryParse. Meaning you pass the number to be added as an out parameter and return a boolean false if the number is not valid

```
public static bool ReadIntegerConsole2(out int number)
{
    int input;
    bool ok = true;

    number = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        number = input;
    else
    {
        ok = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. Please try again: ");
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Now in the calling code you can control the loop knowing the result of the call to ReadInteger2

```
private void SumNumbers() 
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++) 
    {
        Console.Write("Please give the value no. " + index + " (whole number):");
        if(Input.ReadIntegerConsole2(out num))
            sum += num;
        else 
            // Decrement the counter to avoid skipping an input
            index--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to accomplish your goal. But it seems to me one of the most obvious is to follow the example set by `int.TryParse()`, which you are already using. Change your `ReadIntegerConsole2()` method to work the same way:

```
public static bool TryReadIntegerConsole2(out int input)
{
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        return true;

    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. Please try again: ");
    return false;
}
```

Then use it in your loop like this:

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++) // Loop that asks the quesion d
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please give the value no. " + index + " (whole number):");
        } while (!Input.TryReadIntegerConsole2(out num));
        sum += num;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach to avoid touching the index variable

Answer (score 1):

When you are attempting to retrieve the second value continue to loop until the value you retrieve is valid for your case.

```
private int GetUserValue(int index)
{
    var secondValueValid = false;
    int secondValue;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value at index {0}: ", index);
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out secondValue))
        {
            secondValueValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value entered is not a whole integer, please try again.");
        }
    }
    while(!secondValueValid)

    return secondValue;
}
```

This will loop until the user enters a value which is an integer, in which case it will drop out of the loop and return the value entered and in your `SumNumbers` method all you need to do is:

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++)
    {
        num = GetUserValue(index);
        sum += num;
    }
}
```